# member functions and the copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

You have to explicitly list all of the members that you want copied in a copy constructor, this means that you could set up a copy constructor to copy cut down versions of your object.

but how does the member function copying work? are all member functions automatically included? Is this because an object is really just the members and the functions just declare how a class can be used? Does this mean you could in theory create cut down objects with a copy constructor and then, for example, call a getter to get a member that doesn't exist in your copy?

Comment: So you're wondering if you can create a copy of an objectthat is missing certain members?  Or you're wondering if you can create a copy that is missing certain methods?

Comment: It cannot be missing certain members.  The data in those members can however be missing.  If you don't copy over data, then it's not there.  There will still be memory allocated for that property though.  As for not copying methods, as stated below, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a misunderstanding about what classes/objects are in C++.  In some languges (e.g. python), objects can change (new variables/functions); in C++, objects are static, as specified in the class, so there can not be shrinked down version of your object.

The default copy constructor already does a member to member copy.  If this is not enough (shallow copy <-> deep copy), you have to provide your own version of the copy constructor in which you have to do all the copying.  Failing to copy a member will leave the copied version with an undefined or default member.  It is best to avoid having to make your own copy constructor by avoiding dynamic memory and the likes.

Answer (score 6):

Member functions are not stored in class instances. They're just regular functions. A vtable pointer can be stored however. It is used for dynamic dispatch of virtual member functions.

Normal member function calls are determined at compile time.

(as a side-note, there are some languages that do store copies of methods per-instance, although C++ isn't one of them)

Answer (score 4):

Functions don't have a separate instance for each instance; the characteristic of a (non-static) member function isn't that it will be instantiated for each instance, but that it must be called on an instance, and will implicitly receive a pointer to the instance.  There's no copying of functions.  (In fact, functions—member or otherwise—can't be copied.)